# Expected distance between repeated songs in a playlist when shuffling two of every song?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In the typical "shuffle" operation for a playlist of length $N$, we know that there will be $N-1$ songs between successive hearings of any given song.

Now, let's say we shuffle a list of length $2N$, where each song is present twice. How many songs will we hear, on average, before we hear a song for the second time?

Here's my thinking to date:

We can model our songs as a permutation of the multiset $\{1,1,2,2,3,3,....,N,N\}$.

Each such permutation is equally likely. There are $N!$ ways that each song can be separated by 0 songs (shown by multiset above and each permuation of the $N$ "pairs"). There is another $N!$ ways to arrange them to be separated by $N-1$ other songs. In between, we have the remaining $(2N)! - 2(N!)$ arrangements of songs.

This seems combinatorically complicated. Any ideas for proceeding (apart from brute force simulation?)

To clear any confusion, here's the specific quantity I'm interested in:

$$\frac{\sum_1^n d_i}{n}$$ where $d_i$ is the number of songs between repeat hearings of song title $i$.

Comment: You want all of them to be at distance $i$ or that $i$ is the smallest distance in between every song?

Comment: @Phicar neither. What is the average distance between repeated songs when we randomly shuffle songs (where each song is represented twice in the playlist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the expected value of the difference between both appearences of "Despacito" in a random playlist of $2N$ songs (two of those songs are "Despacito").

The answer is

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2N-1} i(2N-i)}{\binom{2N}{2}}=\frac{\binom{2N+1}{3}}{\binom{2N}{2}}=\frac{2N+1}{3}$$

Comment: Almost! See my edit...thanks.

Comment: oh ok, the answer is the same, $d_i$ is a random variable, you are interested in the expected value of the random variable defined as the sum of all $d_i$'s but we can use linearity of expectation.

Comment: For what values of $n$ does your solution hold? $n=2$ should be fixed at $0$, since we have only two of the same song.

Comment: Here, $n=2N$ and $i$ counts the plays *until* the the second song (not *between* the two songs).  So at $n=2$ we get an expected value of $1$ play *until* the song is played again, rather than $0$ songs between them.

Comment: let me relabel following the suggestion by graham

Comment: There, it should be ok now, notice that I am saying that the distance between two consecutive plays is $1$. for the other interpretation just subtract  $1$.